# How to add a class to a span with a particular data-id

Tags: jquery, html

Heat is my question I have a group of spans just like this

```
<div class="mydiv">
    <span data-id="0">hello</span>
    <span data-id="1">how</span>
    <span data-id="2">are</span>
    <span data-id="3">you</span>
</div>
```

using jquery I will get the data id from some where 
like this

```
var dataId = 3;
```

Now I want to add a Class (active) for the span which is having data-id 3 
please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
$('.mydiv span[data-id="3"]').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 3):

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/KZ5wn/7/)

```
$('.mydiv span[data-id="3"]').addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var dataId = 3;    
$("span[data-id=" + dataId + "]").addClass("active");
```